# IF Statements. Grade challenge

Tags: python, if-statement

This code:

```
if grade>=80 and grade<90:
```

it gives me the error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\onura\Desktop\Kodlama Egzersizleri\automate tasks for beginners.py", line 1, in <module>
    if grade>=80 and grade<90:
NameError: name 'grade' is not defined
```

What should I do to define grade?

I just want to run a simple module, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: Can you give a better description of the problem you are facing?

Comment: You're trying to run before you can walk. I suggest looking up tutorials on python

Comment: Please, check [ask]. If this is all your code - well, the `grade` is not defined, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The variable grade must be defined first

```py
grade = 85
if grade >=80 and grade < 90:
...
```

If your grade should be an input from the user, comment that part and add a grade variable like above, then it should work. and so on and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a initial value for your variable, otherwise the interpreter has no way of asserting which is the former value of your variable.
There are several ways of doing it.

#### Approach 1

Either you declare a initial value for your variable, something like

```py
def new_function():
    grade = 82

    #Perform operation with grade

    #If statement
```

#### Approach 2

You can receive `grade` as a parameter to the function. Parameters are arguments that the function receives that can be used during the function execution.

```py
def my_function(grade):
    if(grade >= 80 and grade < 90):
        #Do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    grade = 82
    my_function(grade)
```

But I recommend you start by learning the basics of the language. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined variable grade .
grade = 100
I will recommend you to watch this video
https://youtu.be/EyEqWFvLDT8

If you find this useful please vote me

Try to solve problem first by your own then ask in stack overflow
Don't demotivate on negative votes every learn in thier own pace.

Comment: This video seems to have a lot of valid information, well done.